# What is the meaning of an otherwise empty <div> with the CSS clear:both property?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if anybody knows the meaning of this tag I found in a valid html file I've downloaded.

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Would it have killed you to just look up the CSS standard, and read about what `clear` does?

Comment: Do you guys think such ambigous title be allowed in questions? what does this do?

Comment: This is a legitimate question regardless of whether you think it's obvious or easy to look up.  Relax people.

Comment: @Marcin If he doesn't know about that CSS property probably is not a CSS expert. Do you think a CSS newbie would actually be able to even know where CSS standards are explained?

Comment: This isn't strictly a CSS question though - It's about why the otherwise empty `<div>` exists at all. What purpose does the `<div>` tag serve in this particular instance when it has no content.  It's a valid question.

Comment: @Matteo: I changed the title slightly to make this question more interesting - it's not so much the `clear:both` alone but the purpose of the whole construct here that is interesting. Please feel free to revert my change if you don't like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is known as a "[spacer div](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/)" - the article is now ten years old and at the time this was a good solution to a common problem. It typically appears in scenarios like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:left">
    ...
  <div style="float:left">
    ...
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The inner `div`s are floated - if you simply left out the "spacer div" the container element would not completely enclose its contents (unless you float it itself, which is often impractical). The `&nbsp;` is needed in some older browsers (you know which one) to ensure it behaves as expected in all situations, i.e. a simple `<div style="clear:both"/>` didn't always work - you really needed a `div` with actual (though invisible and nonsensical) content to make it work everywhere.

It's a working solution to a common problem, but there are more elegant ways to solve this, e.g. [using the :after CSS pseudo class](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mbrubeck/clear-after/). This is more elegant because it doesn't require us adding semantically worthless markup elements that are just there for styling purposes. [Another great article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) with a different solution.

Comment: thanks a lot!now it's clear!I found the last link very useful

Answer (score 3):

It clears the floats from both left and right in order to bring the content after it back into the main flow of the page.

[Official definition](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp).

Comment: W3Schools is not "official"; you're thinking of the W3C. More info: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @thirtydot - OK fair enough, interesting link.

Answer (score 0):

This tag will not allow any float to be place either left or right of this tag.