# Height expand with contents

Tags: html, css, height

I have the following horizontal menu:

```
<nav style="min-height: 50px">
    <ul>
        <li style="display: inline;">
            <a href="" style="float: left;">Link text</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the `<nav>` element height to expand with its contents. Now to fix this I could do something like this:

```
<nav style="min-height: 50px">
    <ul>
        <li style="display: inline;">
            <a href="" style="float: left;">Link text</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</nav>
```

This "fix" doesn't look right to me semantically, so is there a cleaner way of achieving the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed more elegant solutions to this phenomenon. The problem is that without help, the parent container does not expand to enclose floated child elements. See also another of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193288/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-otherwise-empty-div-with-the-css-clearboth-property/7193797#7193797) on the topic.

You could use the `:after` pseudo class - add this to your CSS:

```
nav:after {
    content: ""; display: block; height: 0; clear: both;
}
```

or you can use the solution with `overflow: auto` as described [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Comment: Is there a reason why you should use one over another as the overflow one looks far simpler. Thanks for your response.

Comment: ppk calls the `:after` solution the old solution, and I would also tend towards the `overflow: auto` solution - it seems to be the most simple and clean solution if you take the caveats mentioned there into account.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inline-block` instead of `float-left`;

```
<nav style="min-height: 50px">
    <ul>
        <li style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href=""> Link text</a>
        </li>
          <li style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href=""> Link text</a>
        </li>  
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good replacement for `<br style="clear: both;" />` is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#nav`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link for min-height working in all browsers: http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/

```
<nav style="display: block">
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li style="display: inline-block; float: left">
            <a href=""> Link text</a>
        </li>
          <li style="display: inline-block; float: left">
            <a href=""> Link text</a>
        </li>  
    </ul>
</nav>
```